# laravel 5.6 login with restapi instead of database

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i already created the restapi for an app some time ago but now want to hook up laravel as frontend for it. 
i looked around but had some troubel finding a good way of doing it.
basicly what i want is instead of going to the database getting the user data from a rest api. i already have the call to there working.
any idea what the best approuch to this is? 
im thinking about the call in the model but that sounds wrong or creating a custom login function but don't know how to hook into laravel once i know the user login is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it myself. created an auth class that i manually run the users thru. i save the user data in a session to access it when nessesary